# Trying to create data transfer rate calculator using Lazarus and Freepascal

Tags: delphi, freepascal, lazarus, tdatetime

I am trying to add to my application interface a "Transfer Rate : XGb p\min" feature. I am computing it at a millisecond level using Lazarus 1.2.2 and Freepascal 2.6.4.

I have a loop that reads 64Kb blocks from a disk, does stuff with each 64Kb block, and repeats until the whole disk is read or until the user clicks an abort button. I am trying to time how long each read of 64Kb takes and then compute the average rate of data read per minute, i.e. "3Gb per minute".

I have a custom function called 'GetTimeInMilliseconds' that computes the standard time to milliseconds.

Also, to avoid the interface being refreshed ever partial millisecond, I have a counter that tries to ensure the interface is only refreshed every 50 times round the loop, i.e. when 64Kb chunks have been read 50 times, then the counter is reset to 0.

The trouble is, the transfer display is either not getting populated or it gets populated with an inaccurate figure like "234Mb p\min" for a RAID0 device! At other times, it gets something more realistic like "3.4Gb p\min". It should be consistently accurate if ran repeatedly on the same PC and same disk, not inconsistantly inaccurate.

Here is my Try...finally loop that does the looping. It also called FormatByteSize which is a custom function that computers an integer size and converts it into XMb, XGb, XTb etc.

```
var

ProgressCounter, BytesTransferred, BytesPerSecond : integer;

Buffer : array [0..65535] of Byte;   // 65536, 64Kb buffer

ctx : TSHA1Context;

Digest : TSHA1Digest;

NewPos, ExactDiskSize, SectorCount, TimeStartRead, TimeEndRead,
  MillisecondsElapsed, BytesPerMillisecond, BytesPerMinute : Int64;

StartTime, EndTime, TimeTaken : TDateTime;
...
begin
... // Various stuff related to handles on disks etc
 try
    SHA1Init(ctx);
    FileSeek(hSelectedDisk, 0, 0);
    repeat
      ProgressCounter := ProgressCounter + 1; // We use this update the progress display occasionally, instead of every buffer read
      TimeStartRead   := GetTimeInMilliSeconds(Time); // Starting time, in Ms

      // The hashing bit...

      FileRead(hSelectedDisk, Buffer, 65536);  // Read 65536 = 64kb at a time
      NewPos := NewPos + SizeOf(Buffer);
      SHA1Update(ctx, Buffer, SizeOf(Buffer));
      FileSeek(hSelectedDisk, NewPos, 0);
      lblBytesLeftToHashB.Caption := IntToStr(ExactDiskSize - NewPos) + ' bytes, ' + FormatByteSize(ExactDiskSize - NewPos);

      // End of the hashing bit...

      TimeEndRead      := GetTimeInMilliSeconds(Time);;  // End time in Ms
      MillisecondsElapsed := (TimeEndRead - TimeStartRead); // Record how many Ms's have elapsed 

      // Only if the loop has gone round a while (50 times?), update the progress display
      if ProgressCounter = 50 then
        begin
          if (TimeStartRead > 0) and (TimeEndRead > 0) and (MillisecondsElapsed > 0) then // Only do the divisions and computations if all timings have computed to a positive number
            begin
              BytesTransferred := SizeOf(Buffer);
              BytesPerMillisecond := BytesTransferred DIV MilliSecondsElapsed; // BytesPerMillisecond if often reported as zero, even though BytesTRansferred and MilliSecondsElapsed are valid numbers? Maybe this is the fault? 
              BytesPerSecond := BytesPerMillisecond * 1000;  // Convert the bytes read per millisecond into bytes read per second
              BytesPerMinute := BytesPerSecond * 60; // Convert the bytes read per second into bytes read per minute
              lblSpeedB.Caption := FormatByteSize(BytesPerMinute) + ' p\min'; // now convert the large "bytes per minute" figure into Mb, Gb or Tb

              // Reset the progress counters to zero for another chunk of looping
              ProgressCounter := 0;
              BytesPerMillisecond := 0;
              BytesPerSecond := 0;
              BytesPerMinute := 0;
              ProgressCounter := 0;
            end;
        end;
      Application.ProcessMessages;
    until (NewPos >= ExactDiskSize) or (Stop = true); // Stop looping over the disk
    // Compute the final hash value
    SHA1Final(ctx, Digest);
    lblBytesLeftToHashB.Caption:= '0';
  finally
    // The handle may have been released by pressing stop. If not, the handle will still be active so lets close it.
    if not hSelectedDisk = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE then CloseHandle(hSelectedDisk);
    EndTime := Now;
    TimeTaken := EndTime - StartTime;
    lblEndTimeB.Caption := FormatDateTime('dd/mm/yy hh:mm:ss', EndTime);
    if not stop then edtComputedHash.Text := SHA1Print(Digest);
    Application.ProcessMessages;
...

Function GetTimeInMilliSeconds(theTime : TTime): Int64;
// http://www.delphipages.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-135103.html
var
  Hour, Min, Sec, MSec: Word;
begin
  DecodeTime(theTime,Hour, Min, Sec, MSec); 
  Result := (Hour * 3600000) + (Min * 60000) + (Sec * 1000) + MSec;
end;
```

Example:

Form1.Caption := IntToStr( GetTimeInMilliSeconds(Time) );

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I feel that you've made this much more complicated than it needs to be.

Move your file processing code into a separate thread. Within that code, as you finish processing bytes from the file, use `InterlockedAdd` to keep a count of the total number of bytes processed.

In your GUI thread, using a timer of some sort, use `InterlockedExchange` to read the value that `InterlockedAdd` has been modifying and reset it to zero. Then Calculate the amount of time that has passed since the last timer tick. Given the total number of bytes processed within the elapsed time, calculate the bytes per minute and update your GUI.

Since the file operation is on a separate thread, you will not need to worry about how often you update the GUI (although doing so too frequently will be a waste of time).

If you want to calculate the average bytes per minute over the entire operation, don't reset the total byte counter at each tick.

Comment: +1 There's no need for any interlocked operations. The GUI thread can read the instantaneous count of total bytes read. Then it can compare with the value it read on a previous occasion and do the maths. Neither read nor write needs to be atomic.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Agreed, the interlocked operations are not needed as long he ignores my suggestion to reset the byte counter to zero.

Comment: Gents...thanks for the suggestion, though I think I have discovered where the problem is. TimeStartRead & TimeEndRead are actually LESS than a millisecond. So, if TimeStartRead = 12345, and the read takes less than a millisecond, then TimeEndRead also = 12345. So, TimeEndRead - TimeStartRead = 0! I discovered this using epikTimer which allows for nanoseconds (it reported 0.000160 as time taken and is MS based), BUT, it really slows my program down. Not sure why but it made it like 10 times slower! So, what I need is a nanosecond computator built into freepascal. DecodeTime goes only to MS.

Comment: @Gizmo_the_Great you should listen to William. Summing up nanosecond times that measure single "block" reads is just wrong approach as you will rather measure noise than signal, it is not a scientifically reliable measurement method http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observational_error. BTW there are also other threads and processes and context switches consuming the CPU time. So you will not measure pure data transfer rate this way, unless your process runs at very high (not preemptable) priority

Comment: OK - that all makes sense. I thought I might try and use averages over a period of block reads - say 100 or so - rather than computing the time per minute for every single block read. Thanks for all the info - I didn't realise there were so many issues with nanosecond counting until now. Answer accepted and is appreciated, though the implementation of that looks a bit beyond me.